# Array.push pushes the content multiple times

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sockets, functional-programming, react-hooks

```
    useEffect(() => {
    socket.on("private message", ({ content, from }) => {
      console.log(content, from, "content & form");
      for (let i = 0; i < usersList.length; i++) {
        var user = usersList[i];
        if (user.userID === from) {
          console.log("user from");
          user.messages.push({
            content,
            fromSelf: false,
          });
          if (user !== selectedUser) {
            console.log("user to");
            user.hasNewMessages = true;
          }
          break;
        }
      }
    });
  }, [usersList, selectedUser]);
```

I am using socket to make private chat, but the thing is that user.messages.push, pushes the content multiple times because it is inside the for loop, here usersList is a list of all connected users, so if 3 users are connected, it will loop 3 times and then the messages will be pushed 3 times, How do I fix this so that it only pushes one time and not with relative to the number of users connected?

selectedUser is the user that the loggedIn user wishes to initiate a conversation with

**NOTE** : I need a solution except for maintaining a state and then changing it with first iteration and conditionally running the logic, Pls tell me other that this.

Comment: Move the `user.messages.push` out of the loop then? You seem to contradict yourself in what you want the code to do. What are you *actually* wanting pushed into the array? Are you wanting to only push the content into the array if there is *some* user that meets the `user.userID === from` condition?

Comment: Partially correct, see the thing is that i just need to push the {content} inside of an array & it pushes only once the first time but the second time it pushes the content twice and so on it keeps on increasing as the usersList.length increases with every connected users, I just want that in spite of increasing the number of connectedUsers , my message sh0uld be pushed only once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 const messageHandler = ({ content, from }: any) => {
    console.log(content, from, "content & form");
    var user;
    for (let i = 0; i < usersList.length; i++) {
      user = usersList[i];
    }
    if (user && user.userID === from) {
      console.log("user from");
      user.messages.push({
        content,
        fromSelf: false,
      });
      if (user !== selectedUser) {
        console.log("user to");
        user.hasNewMessages = true;
      }
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    socket.on("private message", messageHandler);
  }, [usersList]);
```

This solved the bug, I had to move the Array.push out of the for loop.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: So I guess you really only needed to push into the `messages` array of the last `user` object in `usersList`?

Comment: maybe solved _a_ bug, but there's many more here

Comment: yes @DrewReese, but it shouldnt have been in the for loop

Comment: Pls let me know @Thankyou

Comment: pretty good answer for some people like me who just dont sometimes get how to things work, I was doing a similar thing within a map function. and it gave me so much headache. finally solved.

Answer (score 1):

You are attaching new listeners each time the `useEffect` hook runs after `usersList` or `selectedUser` update. Each time the effect callback runs a new listener is added, and each one runs the same "private message" event callback. This is where the message content duplication is occurring.

I suspect you want only one listener. Use an empty dependency array so the effect runs only once on component mount.

```
const messageHandler = ({ content, from }) => {
  console.log(content, from, "content & form");
  for (let i = 0; i < usersList.length; i++) {
    var user = usersList[i];
    if (user.userID === from) {
      console.log("user from");
      user.messages.push({
        content,
        fromSelf: false,
      });
      if (user !== selectedUser) {
        console.log("user to");
        user.hasNewMessages = true;
      }
      break;
    }
  }
}

useEffect(() => {
  socket.on("private message", messageHandler);
}, []);
```

You may see some lint warning about unspecified dependency on `messageHandler`, if necessary you can disable the linter for this as follows:

```
useEffect(() => {
  socket.on("private message", messageHandler);
  // Run effect only on component mount
  // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
}, []);
```

Comment: This only runs once but, I want the user.messages.push to run everytime there is a new message event

Comment: @1337.ishaan Is this not the case? The effect runs once to instantiate the socket listener, and now whenever a "private message" event/message is received on the socket the `messageHandler` callback is invoked. It's a standard pattern for adding (and removing) listeners.

Comment: I think user.messages.push will not cause a re-render unless there is a dispatch or setState. Apart from that. This answer is perfectly fine @1337.ishaan

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to keep the user.userID in your client and remove the for loop in the socket.on "private message" Event.

Something like this:

```
  // Global (Example values)
  const currentUser = 1;
  const usersList = [2, 3, 4, 5];

  useEffect(() => {
    socket.on("private message", ({ content, from }) => {
      console.log(content, from, "content & form");
        if (currentUser === from) { // The currentUser send a message to another user
          console.log("user from");
          user.hasNewMessages = true;
        } else if (user !== from) { // The currentUser receive a message from another user
            console.log("user to");
            user.messages.push({
                content,
                fromSelf: false,
            });
        }
    });
  }, [usersList, currentUser]);
```

Comment: this is in client, and if I remove the for loop, how will it iterate over the entire JSON and get the data I need from there

Comment: here i cannot loop over all the users and check if the condition ```user.userID === from``` matches

Answer (score 0):

This is what needed to be doing:

```
if (shipments.length > 0) {
    shipments.map((item, key: number) => {
        if (item.lookup_scan === newobj.lookup_scan) {
           shipments[key] = newobj;
        }
    });
    shipments.push(newobj);
} else {
    shipments.push(newobj);
}
```

This is what I was doing:

```
if (shipments.length > 0) {
    shipments.map((item, key: number) => {
        if (item.lookup_scan === newobj.lookup_scan) {
           shipments[key] = newobj;
        } else {
            shipments.push(newobj);
        }
    });
} else {
    shipments.push(newobj);
}
```